# How to append the same variable multiple times that defines a class

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Here is the class `NPC`:

```py
class NPC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = randint(0,800)
        self.y = randint(0,60)
        self.velocity_x = 5
        self.drop_y = 60
        self.img = "my image path here"

npc = NPC()

num_npc = 5
list = []

for i in range(num_npc):
    list.append(npc)
```

In the game loop only one image is shown and is stationary.
I'm working on trying to write old code to be object oriented and can't figure out the best way to render the npcs

Below is the old code I was using and it worked as expected

```py
npc_img = []
npc_x = []
npc_y = []
npc_vel_x = []
npc_vel_y = []
num_of_npc = 5

for i in range(num_of_npc):
    npc_img.append("my img path")
    npc_x.append(random.randint(0, 800))
    npc_y.append(random.randint(0, 60))
    npc_vel_x.append(4)
    npc_vel_y.append(40)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty much correct already.  However the way you are creating *instances* of `NPC` objects is not quite correct.  I guess you meant to add 5 NPCs to the list, not 5 references to the *same* NPC object. That is what your question title says though!

```
npc = NPC()

...

for i in range(num_npc):
    list.append(npc)              # <<-- HERE, same object, 5 times
```

The code should call the NPC constructor in the loop, rather than outside it.

```
for i in range( num_npc ):
    new_npc = NPC()
    list.append( new_npc )
```

While you're rewriting code, it might be worth keeping the co-ordinates and image dimensions in a [Pygame Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), since this allows for easy collision detection and other nice things.

Something like:

```
class NPC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image  = pygame.image.load( "image path here" ).convert_alpha()
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = randint(0,800)
        self.rect.y = randint(0,60)
        self.velocity_x = 5
        self.drop_y = 60
        
    def draw( self, screen ):
        screen.blit( self.image, self.rect )

    def hitBy( self, arrow_rect ):
        hit = self.rect.colliderect( arrow_rect )
        return hit
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still relatively new to python and trying to figure out its quirks. I'm still running into an issue though, in the game window when I render the NPCs I still only see one img not all 5

Comment: @niles87 - Are you sure you're drawing all of them?  `for npc in list: npc.draw( screen )`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, something like this should work:

```
class NPC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = randint(0,800)
        self.y = randint(0,60)
        self.velocity_x = 5
        self.drop_y = 60
        self.image_list = []
        self_image_load_dict = {}

    def add_image(self, image_path):
        self.image_list.append(image_path)

    def load_images(self):
        self.image_load_dict[]
        for i in len(self.get_image_list()):
            self.image_load_dict[i] = pygame.image.load(self.get_image_list()[i])
    
    def get_image_list(self):
        return self.image_list

    def get_image_load_dict(self):
        return self.image_load_dict
```

I used `fstring` so it would be easier to load images and keep track of the image number:

```
npc = NPC()
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_NPC):
    npc.add_image(f"image_path_{i}")
```

Now you have `image_paths` in the object's list, I assume you want to load them, hence the `load_images` method.

NOTE: If needed you can create additional method(s) for loading images. E.g. if you have animations for "left" and "right" movement

I hope this answers your question, if I omitted something please say in comment.